# Is there a way to add Sound to a console program without System.Media

Tags: c#

I had an error when i tried to use System.Media so,
Is there any other package i can use to add Audio?

I used System.Media but when i ran the program it said

`The type name 'SoundPlayer' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Media'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Windows.Extensions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [BUILD6]`

Comment: What is the problem in using `System.Windows.Extensions` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: I kind of dont know how to do that

Comment: I'm new to C# thats why

Comment: Oh wait you mean like 'using System.Windows.Extensions;'??

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Extensions/6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

[NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) is a good library to do what you want. Install it from nuget package installer.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Resources;
using System.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NAudio.Wave;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var reader = new Mp3FileReader(@"Sample.mp3"); // or WaveFileReader(@"Sample.wav")
        var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent(); 
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();
        while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok lemme try one sec

Comment: It works but im using a wav file

Comment: So more errors.

Comment: @AbhinavB: "So more errors" really doesn't provide any useful information. And you shouldn't expect a Stack Overflow answer to contain code that you can just copy/paste without understanding or modifying it, particularly as you haven't even said what you're trying to do. This is just *sample* code showing *one* use of NAudio. If you want to do something else with it, you should look through the NAudio documentation.